# In Oracle, we can get collation details, I would like to how to map the retrieved collation to C# CultureInfo object?

Tags: oracle, collation

I am using this query

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE parameter IN ('NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY')
```

to get the language and territory information.

But when i am trying to create .NET `CultureInfo` object using this information, it throws error.

How to map this?
( or )
Is there any query to get LCID for the language and territory details, this will help to create the culture info object?

Please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that takes the language and territory and returns the cunlture LCID using a `switch`.

Comment: Hi Racil Hilan, Thanks for the quick response. But there are around 300 cultures exists in .net. That will be difficult. I found one database for which language is 'American' and territory is 'America' for which I can not create .Net CultureInfo object.  Any other clue please.

Comment: Do you have to support all of them?

Comment: How to know list of language and territory that are supported in oracle.  And I found one database for which language is 'American' and territory is 'America' for which I can not create .Net CultureInfo object. Any other clue please.

Comment: [See this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/applocaledata.htm#i634428)